# Visual Studio Code C/C++ Extension: is there a intellisenseMode for 32 bit?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see in the documentation that the only two modes for intellisenseMode are clang-x64 and msvc-64x. I work mainly developing FW in 8 and 32b architectures. Is there a setting I can use to make it work properly in those architectures?

Comment: Intellisense is a language-level tool, so it should not care about your target architecture at all.

Comment: Well, actually, when I want to know the size of a struct, if I don't feel like counting bytes and figuring out paddings, I just type `uint32_t size = sizeof(aCertainStruct);` and a mouseover tells me the size. Today I realised that it considers pointers as 8B, which is wrong for my target.

Comment: Apparently, they are working on it https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2312

Answer (score 0):

Since v0.25, 32 bit modes are supported.

(Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2312)